# How to insert a line in the middle of a text file?

Tags: ruby

myFile.txt contains

```
This is a sample file
This contains some data
End of file
```

I will be creating a content string(dynamically) and writing the array inside the file

I tried with r+ mode but it overwrites the existing content

```
file = File.open('myFile.txt','r+')
myString = 'Dynamic content' # varies accordingly for each file based on file
while (line = @file.gets)
  next unless line =~ /sample file/
  @file.puts(myString)
  break
end
```

But It results in myFile.txt contains

```
This is a sample file
Dynamic content
e data
End of file
```

I have tried using with a+ mode and it appends to the last as append mode adds to the last of the file

I was trying to make myFile.txt as

```
This is a sample file
Dynamic content
This contains some data
End of file
```

Is there any other ways/modes in ruby to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of file as a piece of paper. Once you've written something on it, the only safe way to add content is to append. You can't write text in the middle of the paper without overwriting something.

Generally, this kind of insertion is done via a temporary file. It goes like this:

1. Open source file `source` for reading
2. Create a new file `target` for writing
3. Read from `source` up to the point of insertion and write that to `target`
4. Write your new content to `target`
5. Copy the rest of `source` to `target`
6. Close the files
7. Delete/rename `source`
8. Rename `target` to what `source` was named.

Comment: If memory serves, some time in the distant past files were paper (tape or cards).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: oh yes, I've seen factory machines work from [code like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0.jpg).